# SVG path animation issue

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, css-animations

I'm new to CSS animations and I'm struggling to get [this animation](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LENLxM) working.

I've been following this [CSS Tricks post](http://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/).

Currently I don't understand why there are three separate starting point in the animation.

I would like to start from one point, follow the path all the way(doesn't matter which direction) and close the animation at the starting point.

Is that possible? If it is, can anyone tell what's wrong in what I've tried so far?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

This is the code in the demo (I've cut some svg code out):

**HTML**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="3.27778in" height="3.27778in"
     viewBox="0 0 236 236">
  <path class="path"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
        d="M 236.00,0.00
           C 236.00,0.00 236.00,236.00 236.00,236.00
             236.00,236.00 0.00,236.00 0.00,236.00
             0.00,236.00 0.00,0.00 0.00,0.00
             0.00,0.00 236.00,0.00 236.00,0.00 Z
           M 74.00,34.00

          .........

           C 212.00,194.00 213.00,195.00 213.00,195.00
             213.00,195.00 213.00,194.00 213.00,194.00
             213.00,194.00 212.00,194.00 212.00,194.00 Z" />
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it's because of the stroke-dasharray: 1000; what happens if you remove it?

Comment: It can't be that, otherwise how does the animation start? If I remove the image remains static.

Comment: The article talks about the number, 1000 in your example, needing to be big enough. In your case it isn't big enough, it should be at least 2740.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, increase the `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` according to how long your path is.

### [codepen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/XJdgPx)

### [codepen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/JoXJaV) - without the borders

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  animation: dash 20s 1;
}
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="3.27778in" height="3.27778in" viewBox="0 0 236 236">
  <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M 236.00,0.00
           C 236.00,0.00 236.00,236.00 236.00,236.00
             236.00,236.00 0.00,236.00 0.00,236.00
             0.00,236.00 0.00,0.00 0.00,0.00
             0.00,0.00 236.00,0.00 236.00,0.00 Z
           M 74.00,34.00
           C 74.00,34.00 54.00,32.00 54.00,32.00
             59.73,35.89 69.12,35.68 73.85,38.93
             79.05,42.49 78.36,58.39 77.00,64.00
             77.00,64.00 52.00,59.00 52.00,59.00
             56.43,65.82 63.78,61.04 74.00,68.00
             74.00,68.00 56.00,73.60 56.00,73.60
             53.01,74.57 49.98,76.06 47.41,73.60
             42.33,68.43 42.77,58.02 36.00,54.00
             37.16,61.37 39.83,64.58 41.93,71.00
             42.50,72.72 43.33,75.43 41.33,76.58
             37.06,79.03 24.82,72.09 19.00,76.00
             19.00,76.00 38.00,81.00 38.00,81.00
             33.28,87.05 24.22,90.79 22.00,98.00
             25.49,96.51 38.29,87.36 40.23,84.42
             41.25,82.88 40.80,82.84 41.00,82.00
             41.00,82.00 51.00,78.35 51.00,78.35
             51.00,78.35 67.00,73.71 67.00,73.71
             67.00,73.71 76.78,71.78 76.78,71.78
             76.78,71.78 80.48,77.00 80.48,77.00
             80.48,77.00 84.00,94.00 84.00,94.00
             80.23,94.67 68.20,96.98 66.90,91.85
             66.30,89.47 68.62,85.59 69.00,80.00
             69.00,80.00 62.49,90.82 62.49,90.82
             62.49,90.82 54.00,94.00 54.00,94.00
             53.19,91.30 52.67,91.77 50.00,92.00
             55.87,98.01 60.01,94.59 59.00,105.00
             59.00,105.00 67.04,98.60 67.04,98.60
             67.04,98.60 85.00,97.00 85.00,97.00
             85.00,97.00 85.00,137.00 85.00,137.00
             84.98,139.36 85.24,144.44 82.43,145.40
             78.77,146.65 74.50,140.67 67.00,142.00
             66.14,138.99 64.94,139.35 62.00,139.00
             66.19,145.51 79.71,146.43 81.72,152.10
             82.81,155.18 78.24,162.07 76.76,165.00
             72.50,173.39 63.37,188.40 62.00,197.00
             66.37,194.37 68.03,189.44 70.25,185.00
             70.25,185.00 81.20,164.00 81.20,164.00
             82.99,160.47 85.05,155.01 88.21,152.58
             91.43,150.11 107.98,148.29 113.00,147.39
             118.23,146.44 139.09,142.56 143.00,143.43
             146.22,144.15 150.15,147.14 153.00,148.95
             156.73,151.31 162.68,154.48 165.62,157.47
             167.98,159.86 176.04,174.12 178.23,177.96
             180.57,182.08 185.22,189.63 186.18,194.00
             188.01,200.41 183.51,204.14 186.18,213.00
             186.18,213.00 189.00,201.00 189.00,201.00
             197.09,203.50 195.76,209.52 201.00,215.00
             201.34,212.28 201.90,210.92 199.00,210.00
             200.88,201.68 194.91,200.49 195.16,196.14
             195.53,189.51 209.51,193.23 213.00,193.00
             214.14,196.54 214.51,196.72 218.00,198.00
             216.38,192.94 210.53,188.45 205.00,188.72
             202.79,188.83 196.24,191.04 193.02,190.77
             189.28,190.45 188.47,187.82 185.00,187.00
             185.29,180.69 179.76,173.45 176.72,168.00
             175.82,166.37 173.22,162.54 174.82,160.96
             176.23,159.22 180.29,160.67 182.00,160.96
             187.91,162.78 194.92,165.87 201.00,165.00
             203.49,168.01 206.30,167.83 210.00,168.00
             207.31,163.72 204.56,164.32 200.00,162.96
             200.00,162.96 180.00,157.00 180.00,157.00
             180.00,157.00 180.00,155.00 180.00,155.00
             180.00,155.00 200.00,147.56 200.00,147.56
             205.16,145.97 211.08,144.92 214.00,140.00
             211.30,140.62 210.78,140.28 210.00,143.00
             198.29,140.73 177.85,157.17 166.00,152.46
             163.52,151.47 157.21,147.50 155.08,145.82
             153.77,144.79 151.81,143.36 152.91,141.46
             155.31,137.34 165.47,139.09 169.00,134.00
             169.00,134.00 149.00,138.00 149.00,138.00
             149.00,138.00 154.00,123.00 154.00,123.00
             150.14,126.04 148.18,127.93 148.00,133.00
             142.79,134.17 143.44,138.55 137.98,140.35
             137.98,140.35 102.00,146.46 102.00,146.46
             98.91,146.76 92.01,148.56 89.46,146.46
             87.21,145.00 88.05,139.63 87.99,137.00
             87.99,137.00 87.32,127.00 87.32,127.00
             87.65,122.58 88.21,118.48 87.91,114.00
             87.65,110.06 86.61,103.73 88.50,100.05
             89.97,97.18 93.15,96.23 96.00,95.23
             96.00,95.23 120.00,88.65 120.00,88.65
             127.37,88.71 132.25,96.11 141.00,95.00
             141.00,95.00 140.00,97.00 140.00,97.00
             140.00,97.00 143.00,95.00 143.00,95.00
             139.30,93.02 125.70,87.57 124.97,83.82
             124.47,81.20 127.61,77.01 128.00,69.00
             122.58,74.14 124.27,77.91 120.35,82.89
             116.77,87.46 104.77,89.54 99.00,91.34
             96.79,92.03 92.33,93.67 90.13,93.10
             88.00,92.55 87.16,90.87 86.40,88.98
             84.97,85.43 81.60,72.39 84.48,69.60
             87.04,67.12 101.06,67.00 105.00,67.00
             105.00,67.00 105.00,63.84 105.00,63.84
             102.31,64.22 93.70,66.01 91.98,63.84
             90.84,62.15 93.11,60.04 94.09,59.05
             98.59,54.49 100.21,54.33 106.00,53.00
             107.07,57.60 111.67,59.00 116.00,59.00
             116.00,59.00 107.00,50.00 107.00,50.00
             111.64,48.49 119.25,48.00 122.00,44.00
             122.00,44.00 109.00,45.00 109.00,45.00
             109.00,45.00 113.00,36.00 113.00,36.00
             107.32,37.82 104.51,43.68 100.71,48.00
             96.69,52.57 87.45,60.47 82.21,63.00
             81.01,57.47 78.09,42.68 82.21,38.70
             87.21,34.31 102.19,32.67 106.00,27.00
             106.00,27.00 85.00,33.00 85.00,33.00
             85.00,33.00 90.00,21.00 90.00,21.00
             85.47,22.46 84.17,24.25 84.00,29.00
             84.00,29.00 78.90,30.83 78.90,30.83
             78.90,30.83 70.00,20.00 70.00,20.00
             70.00,20.00 69.00,16.00 69.00,16.00
             66.10,20.90 71.91,29.16 74.00,34.00 Z
           M 88.00,34.00
           C 88.00,34.00 87.00,35.00 87.00,35.00
             87.00,35.00 87.00,34.00 87.00,34.00
             87.00,34.00 88.00,34.00 88.00,34.00 Z
           M 103.00,49.00
           C 103.00,49.00 102.00,50.00 102.00,50.00
             102.00,50.00 102.00,49.00 102.00,49.00
             102.00,49.00 103.00,49.00 103.00,49.00 Z
           M 105.00,65.00
           C 105.00,65.00 106.00,66.00 106.00,66.00
             106.00,66.00 106.00,65.00 106.00,65.00
             106.00,65.00 105.00,65.00 105.00,65.00 Z
           M 22.00,75.00
           C 22.00,75.00 21.00,76.00 21.00,76.00
             21.00,76.00 21.00,75.00 21.00,75.00
             21.00,75.00 22.00,75.00 22.00,75.00 Z
           M 126.00,75.00
           C 126.00,75.00 125.00,76.00 125.00,76.00
             125.00,76.00 125.00,75.00 125.00,75.00
             125.00,75.00 126.00,75.00 126.00,75.00 Z
           M 196.00,147.00
           C 196.00,147.00 195.00,148.00 195.00,148.00
             195.00,148.00 195.00,147.00 195.00,147.00
             195.00,147.00 196.00,147.00 196.00,147.00 Z
           M 156.00,148.00
           C 156.00,148.00 155.00,149.00 155.00,149.00
             155.00,149.00 155.00,148.00 155.00,148.00
             155.00,148.00 156.00,148.00 156.00,148.00 Z
           M 212.00,194.00
           C 212.00,194.00 213.00,195.00 213.00,195.00
             213.00,195.00 213.00,194.00 213.00,194.00
             213.00,194.00 212.00,194.00 212.00,194.00 Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: That's exactly it thank you, with no border too! How did you get rid of the border? I'd like to get rid of the dots that appears at the start. thanks so much!

Comment: @Dura - I removed it from your path.

Comment: Hi, sorry I realised that. I meant how did you figure out which bits of the path to remove?

Comment: @Dura - The `M 236.00,0.00 .... 236.00,0.00 Z` in the `d` attribute was creating the border. I removed it. The `M` basically means move to the co-ordinate `236.00,0.00` and `Z` means close the path. After that there is another move(`M`) command which is where the main path starts from.